# Combine data validation code in more columns

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to combine the code below with a second (separate) rolelist and second column:

```
Const RolesList As String = "Admin"
Const FirstCellAddress As String = "B2"
```

One problem I have is that I can't use: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` a second time in the same worksheet.

How can I combine more rolelists and other columns in this code so I can use this data validation code for other columns?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const RolesList As String = "Moderator"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const Delimiter As String = "||"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
    
    Dim rng As Range
    With Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Set rng = Intersect(.Resize(.Worksheet.rows.Count - .Row + 1), Target)
    End With
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        cel.Value = removeTrail(cel.Value, Delimiter)
    Next cel
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Dim Roles() As String: Roles = Split(RolesList, ",")
    
    Dim dRng As Range
    Dim aRng As Range
    Dim Curr() As String
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim isFound As Boolean
    
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If Not IsError(cel) Then
            Curr = Split(cel.Value, Delimiter)
            For n = 0 To UBound(Curr)
                cMatch = Application.Match(Curr(n), Roles, 0)
                If IsError(cMatch) Then
                    isFound = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If StrComp(Curr(n), Roles(cMatch - 1), _
                            vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
                        isFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
            If isFound Then
                isFound = False
                If dRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set dRng = cel
                Else
                    Set dRng = Union(dRng, cel)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    
    rng.Interior.Color = xlNone
    If Not dRng Is Nothing Then
        dRng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
    Worksheets(1).Columns(12).Calculate
End Sub

Function removeTrail( _
    ByVal SearchString As String, _
    ByVal RemoveString As String, _
    Optional ByVal doTrim As Boolean = True) _
As String
    If doTrim Then
        removeTrail = Trim(SearchString)
    Else
        removeTrail = SearchString
    End If
    If Right(removeTrail, Len(RemoveString)) = RemoveString Then
        removeTrail = Left(removeTrail, Len(removeTrail) - Len(RemoveString))
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: So you want to run the same code twice, but with the two constants changed? You could break out the code into a new sub, and then call it twice from the change event.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, I can try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would be minimal effort?
Making the constants into variables, and calling them from the `Worksheet_Change` event. *(untested example)*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   

   Call newSub ("Moderator", "A2", Target)
   Call newSub ("Admin", "B2", Target)

End Sub


Private sub newSub(RolesList As String, FirstCellAddress As String, Target as range)
   Const Delimiter As String = "||"

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
   ....

   ....
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank I will try this!

Comment: If I do this, where do I put the RoleList and FirstCellAddress ?

Comment: Oh nvm let me look at it again!